# Function where characters will either +1 or -1

Tags: python

Implement a function crypto() where every character at a odd position i in the alphabet will be encrypted with the character at position i+1 and every character at an even position i will be encrypted with the character at position i-1.  Or like, 'a' is encrypted with 'b', 'b' with 'a', 'c' with 'd', 'd' with 'c', 'e' with 'f', 'f' with 'e', etc.

This should appear:

```
>>>>crypto('abc')

bad

>>>>crypto('OOZ')

PPY
```

***ATTEMPT

```
def crypto():
    return [ord(c) in s]
s = 'cat'
alist = ascii_list(s)
print alist

alist[0] +=1
alist[1] +=14
```

I'm almost positive I'm coming at this all wrong.

Comment: "thinking about using ord and chr".  Good.  Write some of that.  And post what you've tried.

Comment: when you say odd, do you mean ascii value is odd or a=0 ... is odd?

Comment: based on OP if a -> b then a must be odd.  as it turns out, the ascii value for a is also odd, so the ord approach should work well

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: def crypto():
    return [ord(c) in s]
s = 'cat'
alist = ascii_list(s)
print alist

alist[0] +=1
alist[1] +=14

Comment: 6 lines. But I'm a little crazy.

Comment: Well, 2 lines if you use that malignancy of a trinary.

Comment: Winning the competition for most useless tag imaginable on SO: "Coding"

Comment: If only it was the other way around (ie odd-1, even+1), the answer would be a plain `chr(ord(c)^1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
def crypto(s):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c)+(1 if ord(c)%2 else -1)) for c in s)
```

EXPLANATION:

1. get the ordinal number for each character `c` in the string `s` (that's `for c in s` part)
2. Notice that `ord('a')` and `ord('A')` are both odd (very useful!), so ...
3. ... `(1 if ord(c)%2 else -1)` part evaluates to `1` for odd `ord(c)` and `-1` for even ones
4. add the value obtained above to the `ord(c)` and use `chr` to obtain the "encrypted" character
5. glue everything together with a `''.join()`

Comment: This will also affect characters outside the alphabet.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the answer, I'd like to know the logic behind this please.

Answer (score 5):

Separate this problem into two parts:

1. Given a character, what character should it encrypt to? You're on the right track by using the `ord` function here. You can write a simple function that takes in a letter and returns the letter it should be encrypted to, if it should be changed at all.
2. How do you go through the string and get each letter into that function?